# Как получить код авторизации в Google PLay Service для Unity в новой версии SDK (v2)?

Tags: unity3d, firebase, auth, google-play-services

Авторизация в Unity через Google PLay Service
До версии 0.11.01, получить код авторизации можно было следующим образом

```
  Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
      if (success) {
          **authCode** = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
      }
  });
```

После недавнего перехода на Play Games Services v2 SDK этот метот пропал.
Подскажите, кто знает, как можно получить код для последующей авторизации через Firebase

```
Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(**authCode**);
```

Comment: Возможно ваше решение где то тут: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1732, есть полезные рекомендации, я думаю стоит посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ветка относится к версии SDK, когда метод GetServerAuthCode() ещё существовал. Сейчас его нет. А гугл ещё не обновил документацию для Unity по авторизации.